# Hooked Events for internet explorer is not working some times

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, events

I am trying to register the events from internet explorer. Following is the code and its working fine.

```
public void Start()
        {
            shellWindows.WindowRegistered -= new SHDocVw.DShellWindowsEvents_WindowRegisteredEventHandler(shellWindows_WindowRegistered);
            shellWindows.WindowRegistered += new SHDocVw.DShellWindowsEvents_WindowRegisteredEventHandler(shellWindows_WindowRegistered);
            shellWindows.WindowRevoked -= new SHDocVw.DShellWindowsEvents_WindowRevokedEventHandler(shellWindows_WindowRevoked);
            shellWindows.WindowRevoked += new SHDocVw.DShellWindowsEvents_WindowRevokedEventHandler(shellWindows_WindowRevoked);

            "Listening to web events".AppendToTextFile(logFilePath);
            StartListening();
        }
```

The StartListening() function shown above binds the document events for the internet explorer tab. The binding function is also defining below.

```
 private void BindDocumentEvents(InternetExplorer ie)
        {
            try
            {
                HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)ie.Document;
                HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event docEvents = doc as HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event;
                docEvents.onclick += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(htmlDoc_Click);
                docEvents.onkeyup += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onkeyupEventHandler(htmlDoc_KeyUp);
                //docEvents.onkeypress += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onkeypressEventHandler(htmlDoc_KeyPress);
                docEvents.onselectionchange += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onselectionchangeEventHandler(htmlDoc_Selectionchange);
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Exception code: {0}", e.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Exception description: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }

        }
```

The bind events and its binding functions shown above like 'htmlDoc_Click' is working only for sometimes and the binding breaks.

Comment: Consider posting a [MCVE].